# FTL arithmetic operation

Tags: freemarker

I'm facing a error like below :

```
My Ftl was at first as below :
{
  "U": ${num} + 1
}
```

but output was

```
{
  "U": 10 + 1
}
```

so tried to change the string to Number:

```
{
  "U": ${num?number} + 1
}
```

But now getting the error :
The following has evaluated to null or missing: num

```
Expectation is:
{
  "U": 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
My Ftl was at first as below :
{
  "U": ${num + 1}
}
```

The things inside `${}` (and `<#...>` etc.) are interpreted as template language, anything outside them is just text to output as is.